# Are there a list of common UI patterns to implement collections of "has_many" objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns

I frequently end up with projects containing idioms such as "Category has_many Products". I always find myself struggling with the thought process around implementing it in a user-friendly way.

If you take the plain scaffolding that Rails 3.2.3 offers, which combined with the simple_form gem are really great for small, simple apps, then you are given the skeleton that you need to create, for example, both products and categories.

Now I am in the situation of how to add many Products to a Category. Depending on the size of the potential result set, I typically put a little search box on a page and then list the child objects at the bottom, and make it as Ajax-y as necessary.

But where do I give access to this? Should it be on the "Show" view? Or should I dispense with the Show action altogether and simply redirect back to the Index list and put an additional action on there called "Products" right next to Edit and Destroy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends how your application flow is.
I'm not sure if this is really about Rails, but for example in Magento (its a shop) admin panel, when you're editing category, there is tab to manage associated products, so you can view a list of 'em and using checkbox to assign product so category (with more sophisticated filtering). Similar for product, when editing it, under 'category' tab you can use checkboxes to assign it to proper cat.

As for Rails - if my set is not big, I personally use list of categories under product, with checkboxes or jQuery autocomplete field with 'facebook style' tags ;-)